# How to calculate percent change from irregular intervals from long form data

Tags: sql, teradata

I have data in table P

```
id    bmi    contact_date
1     25     01/01/2015
1     26     06/15/2015
2     20     01/01/2014
3     21     03/12/2014
3     22     04/15/2015
3     NULL   09/12/2015
3     23     12/10/2015
```

What I would like to do using SQL is get the percent change in BMI between the two most recent values for each id (ie one row per id). If there are not two values, then I simply want for there to be a '0'.

```
id   change
1     .04
2      0
3     .045
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the two most recent values using OLAP-functions and then it's just applying the percent calculation:

```
SELECT id,
  Coalesce((Cast(bmi AS DECIMAL(8,3)) /  -- most recent bmi
            Min(bmi)                     -- 2nd most recent bmi
            Over (PARTITION BY id
                  ORDER BY contact_date DESC
                  ROWS BETWEEN 1 Following AND 1 Following)) - 1
          , 0)
FROM tab t
WHERE bmi IS NOT NULL
QUALIFY -- this returns the most recent row 
   Row_Number()
   Over (PARTITION BY id 
         ORDER BY contact_date DESC) = 1
```

This assumes that `bmi` (*body mass index*) will never be zero, but in your comment you noted a *division by zero* error. You better remove zeros by switching to `WHERE bmi > 0` (which also excludes NULLs).

Or change zeroes to NULL BY adding `NULLIF` like this:

```
Coalesce((Cast(bmi AS DECIMAL(8,3)) /  -- most recent bmi
          NullIf(Min(bmi)                     -- 2nd most recent bmi
                 Over (PARTITION BY id
                       ORDER BY contact_date DESC
                       ROWS BETWEEN 1 Following AND 1 Following),0)) - 1
        , 0)
```

Comment: sorry, I think I must have done something wrong because your code returns only 0s in the column for the coalesce statement. One thing I realized I had not accounted for is that there are some instances where there is no bmi recorded. I addressed this by adding to your code a WHERE bmi is NOT NULL but got the error Teradata row not delivered(trget): Invalid calculation: division by zero. Thoughts on where I am going wrong?

Comment: @Scott: It should work now, the *division by zero* error indicates there are actually zeros, you should remove them as a bmi of zero is not possible. Check my modifed query (this time actually tested)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the row_number function to get the values on the first two rows and calculate the percentage change.

```
select id, 
coalesce((max(case when rn=1 then bmi end) - max(case when rn=2 then bmi end))
         /(1.0*max(case when rn=2 then bmi end)),0) change
from (select t.*, row_number() over(partition by id order by contact_date desc) rn
      from tablename t) x
group by id
```

Comment: your code also returns a column of zeros for me coming from the coalesce statement. I think I have made an error in describing (simplifying) my data. I edited to include that bmi can be null. I added this to your code via WHERE bmi IS NOT NULL but 0s were still returned in the column.

Comment: did you include multiplication by 1.0 or exclude it?

Comment: I included multiplication by 1.0